# What are marine fungi like?

Tags: mycology, marine-biology

Particularly, what is their mycelium like and where exactly do they grow it?

I imagine that their spores travel though water same as terrestrial fungi travel through air until they stumble upon solid food (a carcass, a living host, sea floor rich with organic remains etc), at which point they begin growing mycelium network though that object. While I understand that there are many species of marine fungi, is my understanding generally correct?

Also, are there any fungi plankton: that constantly float in the water column and extract nutrients right from it, without ever having to "settle down"? If yes, do such fungi grow some special, "floating" version of mycelium?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: In addition, this site works well for focused questions rather than broad overviews of a subject. Have you read the most relevant [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marine_fungi)? Note that also has an extensive references section that you can get into. Also, how about one of these freely available [review](https://journals.asm.org/doi/10.1128/mBio.01189-18) [articles](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0960982219301484)?

Comment: @tyersome, I thought that the specificity of my question details should be evidence enough that I've looked and given quite some thought to the question myself. I even provided my understanding of what the the answer could be and asked for confirmation. I've read some articles and the wiki page: while they give a lot of specific detail (like habitats, distribution etc), I didn't quite get the impression of what they are like. Especially in terms of mycelium: because it's the key feature of terrestrial fungi, but at the same time doesn't quite make sense to have in open water.

Comment: As currently written your question seems to be asking for a review of an entire kingdom in multiple habitats across ~70% of this planet. I hope you can see that that isn't a reasonable question for this site, which is why your post has two close votes for "Needs more focus". If your primary question is about the growth form of planktonic fungi, then please [edit] your title and body to focus on that. It is important to clearly ask a single question (per post) as this ensures that you get a clear answer and that others can find this by searching. It will also helps you search more effectively.